# PHP Validate required field + age validation in one function

Tags: php, validation, required, date

I have a registration form with a required date of birth field.

```
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_dob; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>"   /><p id="age"></p>
        <?php if ($error_dob) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_dob; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
```

So in my php controller file [ I am using a software coded in MVC], I Have the following the following function to make the field required:

```
 if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) > 32)) {
        $this->error['dob'] = $this->language->get('error_dob');
    }
```

I also need to validate if the user is a least 19 years old. If he/she is not, an error will be displayed, I am using the following function in the same php controller file to achieve this:

```
$allowed_age = 19;
$bdate = strtotime($_REQUEST['dob']);
$age = (time()-$bdate)/31536000;
if($age < $allowed_age) {
 $this->error['dob'] = $this->language->get('error_dob');
}
```

And I have tested it and it seems to be working properly. However, I was wondering how can I validate the two things at once. I mean, validate if the user has input the dob, and if the age is older than 19.

I am not an expert, so if you know a better way to achieve this, please share it.

Best Regards,

Codekmarv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this to get the age

```
$age = floor( (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) - strtotime($this->request->post['dob'])) / 31556926);
```

and after that take `$age` value and just check it in if condition

```
if (((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) > 32)) 
&& $age < 19) {
    $this->error['dob'] = $this->language->get('error_dob');
}
```

It will check for user has inputed a value and age is greater than 19.

You have to use `&&` operator to check multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help. I tried to use your code but it's failing to validate if the age is older than 19. Does it make any difference if the dob is coming from ui datepicker?

Comment: @codekmarv can you explain `it's failing to validate if the age is older than 19.`. Try to print `$age` value and when should it give error when the age is greater than 19 or less than 19.

Comment: What I mean is that it is checking if the user chose the date of birth, it is showing the error when no dob was chosen, so this part is ok; however, it is not checking if the age is greater than 19, if it is less, it should throw the error. See here: [link](http://opencartdev.technopolaris.com/tpoc1541/index.php?route=account/register)

Comment: not sure how to check the value in $age, but I can tell you it's doing its job, it's getting the age. What is failing if the combination of the functions (the one two check if the user gave the dob works, but the other to check if the user is older than 19 is not working). If I  separate them, they both work.

Comment: so there must be something here we're missing, and this php part is actually new for me, so I am clueless  `if (((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['dob'])) > 32)) && $age > 19) {
    $this->error['dob'] = $this->language->get('error_dob');
} `

Comment: store `$age` value in a variable and show it,just like you are doing it for showing error.

Comment: I found the problem the condition should be `$age < 19`, and I have putted `$age > 19`. Now it will work.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Still no luck. I don't understand why it's not working because if I use  your function to get the age, and the following validation  separate, it works: `if($age < 19) {
 $this->error['dob'] = $this->language->get('error_dob');
}`

Comment: do this `|| $age < 19` instead of `&& $age < 19`. It should work.

Comment: Wonderful! It works. Thanks a lot!! I really appreciate your help and time. If you ever come to Costa Rica, I'll invite you a cup of coffee :)  It is a lot better now, much cleaner than the original I had.